# Assigning Final variables from constructors | not allowed from methods. Why?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, final

Practicing some code samples and i have came across this:
I have declared final variables at class level and trying to assign values from methods, lead to compile time error(code-2). But from constructor it did get assigned(code-1).

code-1:

```
class Immutable {

    private final int age;
    private final String name;

    private Immutable(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
```

code-2:

```
class Immutable {

    private final int age;
    private final String name;

    private void me() {
        this.age = 19;
        this.name = "name";
    }
```

Of-course, they could be assigned at class level too but, not allowed to do in constructors again, since they are allowed to declare only once. But, why are final variables assigned in constructors and not from methods?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Constructors are executed once. Methods can be executed multiple times. Assignments to final variables are only permitted once - it's as simple as that. (If they could be assigned different values after construction, they wouldn't be very "final" would they? C# permits readonly variables to be set multiple times, but still only within the constructor... Java is just a bit stricter than that.)

Answer (score 5):

Formally, this behaviour is defined in the [Java Language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2):

> **8.3.1.2. final Fields**
>
> A blank final instance variable must be definitely assigned (§16.9) at the end of every constructor (§8.8) of the class in which it is declared; otherwise a compile-time error occurs.

The reason is that it would otherwise be huge effort (if not impossible) for the compiler to detect whether the variable was already assigned earlier when another assignment is done in any other method. The constructor is only executed once, while any other method can be executed more than once - hence checking if a field was initialized within the constructor is much easier for the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

> But, why are final variables assigned in constructors and not from methods?

It is because being a method, there is always a tendency that the method will be called again even if you set the method as `private`. Other methods which is `public` or `protected` may still be able to invoke it and those non-private methods calling it can be called outside the class.

So the only place where allows the value to be assigned only once is in the constructor (which will only be invoked when object is instantiated).